# How to remove all special characters and spaces except Comma(,), Colon(:),Double quote(") and curly braces of a string PHP

Tags: php, json, regex

How can i clean this JSON String data ?. At first look it is very easy using **str_replace** method but its not. This JSON string is form JSON object that has spaces for ex . {" First Name  ": "something"} . so when i converted this into json string the empty spaces replaced by unwanted strings(\u00a0) . I think this problem can be solve using **preg_replace** but the suddenly i dont know the regex for comma,double quote,colon. This characters is necessary for json string format. Please help me.

for example

```
       {"AS_applicant_Data__c":
            "{
                \"Last Name\u00a0\":\"SDFSAD\",
                \"First Name\u00a0\":\"SDFAFSDA\",
                \"Middle Name\u00a0\":\"SAFDSAFD\",
                \"Gender\u00a0\":\"Male\"
            }"
        }
```

to

```
        {"AS_applicant_Data__c":"
            "{
                "Last Name":"SDFSAD",
                "First Name":"SDFAFSDA",
                "Middle Name":"SAFDSAFD",
                "Gender":"Male"
            }"
        }
```

Comment: How was the json generated in the first place? Additionally, does `str_replace("\\u00a0", "", $str);` work (mind the escaped backslash in the beginning).

Comment: From a js library .. that's why It gives me headache . I know php method preg_replace method can solve this problem without modifying the js library.

Comment: i already tried that line of codes already.. does't good happen.

Comment: What is the name of the js library?

Comment: https://github.com/dobtco/formrenderer-base ..

Answer (score 3):

I use this code and it looks ok to me:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOD
{"AS_applicant_Data__c":
    "{
        \"Last Name\u00a0\":\"SDFSAD\",
        \"First Name\u00a0\":\"SDFAFSDA\",
        \"Middle Name\u00a0\":\"SAFDSAFD\",
        \"Gender\u00a0\":\"Male\"
    }"
}
EOD;
$pattern = '#\\\\u[0-9a-f]{4}#i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

?>
```

This regular expression is blindly replace Unicode char in a format of \uxxxx with empty string. If you know for certain that there's only \u00a0, you can change regex to `#\\\\u00a0#i`

Try a quick run here: http://ideone.com/xW4zTN

Comment: maybe you have to tell me why it doesn't

Comment: That characters are computer generated replacement for spaces when during conversion of json object into json string

Comment: When i use this **preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $str);
** .. it will remove all the special characters. is it possible to skip the comma,double quotes,curly braces and colon ? so we can output json string format ?

Comment: why not using what I suggest ? `preg_replace("#\\\\u[0-9a-f]{4}#i", "", $str);`

Comment: function clean($str){

   
  $str = preg_replace("#\\\\u[0-9a-f]{4}#i", "", $str);

  return $str;
 }

print_r(clean($val_data)); <- nothing happens

Comment: i will sent to a screen shot

Comment: I recommend you to just write a simple test case and start from there.
The function should work as it is now.

Comment: tnx for your effert.. i will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

> When i use this `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $str);` .. it will
>   remove all the special characters. is it possible to skip the
>   comma,double quotes,curly braces and colon ?

Of course it is, just include those special characters in the character class (the quotation mark has to be escaped with a backslash):

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z,\"{}:]/", "", $str);
```